# SharePoint Scheduling

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, design, schedule

I am working on a project right now that involves several lists related to employee availability and asset availability (e.g. vacation, project travel, etc.).  These lists are populated by various forms with extensive workflows behind them, and everything seems good.  However, I am looking for a way to display all of this information in a schedule view, somewhat similar to a Gantt chart.  As one view, I would like to be able to have a collapsible 'Trip', with associated assets and employees within this category, and have each individual asset / employee / trip have a schedule shown to the right (a broken line showing unavailable periods).  I am not able to get code onto our server, so I have to do this all OOB.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about this?  Is there a way to import all of this data to Project and aggregate it?  Maybe it would be best to create some sort of Access report for viewing on SharePoint?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**  I have come across some screenshots of Team Planner from Project Pro 2010- that is exactly the sort of view that I am looking for.  I can't find any information indicating that there is a way to get this view directly into SharePoint, but if my description wasn't clear enough, this is what I'm trying to get (without the drag-and-drop capability- I would like mine to be read-only):
[image: Team Planner Interface]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a **Project Task tracker** (out-of-the box).  You can get a certain amount of functionality out of it without hacking into it - but even if you used a content-editor webpart, you *could* [add some custom javascript like this](http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2011/07/09/sharepoint-2010-customizing-the-gantt-view-and-the-client-grid/).

Your screenshot illustrates GANNT view - which is one of the possible view types of an OOB Sharepoint Project Tracking page.  Go to *Create > Tracking* and create a new *Project Task*.  The *Project Task* tracking list looks just about what have there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, BGM, but this doesn't seem to be QUITE what I'm looking for.  As far as customization goes, I am not able to put any code on the server per corporate regulations- if I was, I think this project would have been finished a long time ago.  Secondly, I'm not actually looking for a GANTT view, but rather something similar.  What I am looking for is something like the Team Planner, where there will be a series of segments on each line (each line corresponding to an individual / machine) that will indicate their location, rather than a single line from start to end.

Comment: If you are OOB, can't you use a Content Editor web-part?  That's not really "code on the server" - its javascript in a web part - completely OOB.  As for the gannt, if you specify the start date and end date the same field, you have dots instead of lines.  It's a workaround, I confess.